# Scrapy Spider Close

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a script that I need to run after my spider closes. I see that Scrapy has a handler called spider_closed() but what I dont understand is how to incorporate this into my script. What I am looking to do is once the scraper is done crawling I want to combine all my csv files them load them to sheets. If anyone has any examples of this can be done that would be great.

Answer (score 5):

As per the example in the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html), you add the following to your Spider:

```
# This function remains as-is.
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super().from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    return spider

# This is where you do your CSV combination.
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    # Whatever is here will run when the spider is done.
    combine_csv_to_sheet()
```

Comment: I see bu what if I am running multiple spiders. I need to know when the last spider has closed. How would that work in this case?

Comment: How do you run your multiple spiders? If you kick them off one-by-one then I'm not sure if there is a built-in way to do it. However, if you start multiple spiders using [this method from the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process), then you won't use a signal and  you can simply run your code at the end.

Comment: Yes, that's how I am doing it I am running all four spiders through crawl process. I think I see what youre saying I can write the script right below the crawl spider processes and once those are done the next line of code can combine the data into one sheet?

Comment: Yes! That's the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments on my [other answer about a signal-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54656968/4082726), here is a way to run some code after *multiple* spiders are done. This does not involve using the `spider_closed` signal.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('spider1')
process.crawl('spider2')
process.crawl('spider3')
process.crawl('spider4')
process.start()

# CSV combination code goes here. It will only run when all the spiders are done.
# ...
```